# Crash in production build only, EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, swift

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000

2 UIKitCore -[UIView traitCollection] + 176

This crash is only happening in production and on iOS 12 devices. The only line in the crash report that is part of my app is the AppDelegate class definition which obviously isn't helpful.

I have tried opening it up using the Crashes Organizer and it doesn't seem to know what to do when I hit "Open in Project". This crash is mostly happening in iOS 12 but have seen a couple instances on iOS 11.

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,2
Version:             1 (4.2.1)
AppStoreTools:       10B63
AppVariant:          1:iPhone9,2:12
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2018-12-31 22:15:33.6264 -0600
Launch Time:         2018-12-31 22:14:09.4376 -0600
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.1.2 (16C101)
Baseband Version:    5.30.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4374282240
    REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
    UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
    __TEXT                 0000000104ba4000-0000000104ba8000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...p/MyApp

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [6155]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019bad487c lookUpImpOrForward + 156 (objc-runtime-new.h:1269)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019bad4870 lookUpImpOrForward + 144 (objc-runtime-new.mm:514)
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019bae1098 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 56
3   UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca08e5a0 -[UIView traitCollection] + 176 (UIView.m:0)
4   UIKitCore                       0x00000001c982ebdc -[UIGestureRecognizer _inForceCapableEnvironment] + 48 (UIGestureRecognizer.m:1667)
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001c982891c -[UIGestureRecognizer setView:] + 324 (UIGestureRecognizer.m:468)
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001c9832e34 -[UILongPressGestureRecognizer setView:] + 84 (UILongPressGestureRecognizer.m:186)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca0b2770 -[UIView(Internal) _addGestureRecognizer:atEnd:] + 252 (UIView.m:14622)
8   UIKitCore                       0x00000001c9ea87ec -[UITextInteraction didMoveToView:] + 252 (UITextInteraction.m:310)
9   UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca0b5ff0 _setInteractionView + 84 (UIView.m:15244)
10  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca0b5ed4 -[UIView(Dragging) addInteraction:] + 208 (UIView.m:15260)
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c9ea88bc -[UITextInteraction didMoveToView:] + 460 (UITextInteraction.m:314)
12  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca0b5ff0 _setInteractionView + 84 (UIView.m:15244)
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca0b5ed4 -[UIView(Dragging) addInteraction:] + 208 (UIView.m:15260)
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c9ea88bc -[UITextInteraction didMoveToView:] + 460 (UITextInteraction.m:314)
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca0b5ff0 _setInteractionView + 84 (UIView.m:15244)
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca0b5ed4 -[UIView(Dragging) addInteraction:] + 208 (UIView.m:15260)
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c9ea88bc -[UITextInteraction didMoveToView:] + 460 (UITextInteraction.m:314)
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca0b5ff0 _setInteractionView + 84 (UIView.m:15244)
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca0b5ed4 -[UIView(Dragging) addInteraction:] + 208 (UIView.m:15260)
20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c9ebfc74 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) addGestureRecognizersToView:] + 1192 (UITextInteractionAssistant.m:794)
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c9ebf724 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setGestureRecognizers] + 204 (UITextInteractionAssistant.m:0)
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c9ebe1e8 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) initWithView:textInteractionSet:] + 124 (UITextInteractionAssistant.m:226)
23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c9f14924 -[UITextField _createInteractionAssistant] + 80 (UITextField.m:7609)
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c9f149c0 -[UITextField willMoveToWindow:] + 132 (UITextField.m:7620)
25  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca0a0b18 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:] + 804 (UIView.m:10262)
26  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca0b0f2c -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 424 (UIView.m:14253)
27  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca086a68 -[UIView _setTraitStorageSubviews:] + 548 (UIView.m:0)
28  Foundation                      0x000000019d2a529c -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 272 (NSKeyValueCoding.m:418)
29  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca0b702c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 180 (UIView.m:15515)
30  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c98ba6d4 -[NSObject(UIIBPrivate) _uikit_applyValueFromTraitStorage:forKeyPath:] + 60 (_UITraitStorage.m:39)
31  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c98bc828 -[_UIRelationshipTraitStorage applyRecordsMatchingTraitCollection:] + 1220 (_UITraitStorage.m:395)
32  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c98baec4 -[NSObject(_UITraitStorageAccessors) _applyTraitStorageRecordsForTraitCollection:] + 244 (_UITraitStorage.m:156)
33  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca08e9bc -[UIView _traitCollectionDidChangeInternal:] + 104 (UIView.m:5513)
34  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca08ecdc -[UIView _wrappedProcessTraitCollectionDidChange:forceNotification:] + 128 (UIView.m:5573)
35  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c9ffa4e0 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateEx... + 116 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4172)
36  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca08efd0 -[UIView _processDidChangeRecursivelyFromOldTraits:toCurrentTraits:forceNotification:] + 132 (UIView.m:5604)
37  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ca0b776c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1268 (UIView.m:15686)
38  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a0ef5b74 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184 (CALayer.mm:9445)
39  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a0efab2c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 324 (CALayer.mm:9325)
40  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a0e5944c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 340 (CALayer.mm:2463)
41  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a0e87d7c CA::Transaction::commit() + 608 (CATransactionInternal.mm:425)
42  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c9c37a3c _afterCACommitHandler + 256 (UIApplication.m:2782)
43  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c8887cc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1822)
44  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c883460 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412 (CFRunLoop.c:1932)
45  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c883a00 __CFRunLoopRun + 1264 (CFRunLoop.c:2950)
46  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c8831f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
47  GraphicsServices                0x000000019eafc584 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
48  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c9c0ed40 UIApplicationMain + 212 (UIApplication.m:4347)
49  MyApp                           0x0000000104babe54 0x104ba4000 + 32340
50  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019c342bb4 start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000001   x1: 0x0000000104fa6e40   x2: 0x000000028388fcc0   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x00000002812ba0a0   x7: 0x0000000000000d90
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x2c49510395fc0044  x10: 0x0000000104f76998  x11: 0x0000000104c8b43c
x12: 0x0000000104f8f1f8  x13: 0x0000000104fa6e40  x14: 0x000000000000000a  x15: 0x00000001ca1a3890
x16: 0x0000000104fa6e40  x17: 0xc00000019c000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001d6841ed8
x20: 0x0000000283665e00  x21: 0x00000001ca156324  x22: 0x0000000104fa6e40  x23: 0x0000000000000001
x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x0000000105572c60  x27: 0x000000012a229a00
x28: 0x0000000100000002   fp: 0x000000016b256a30   lr: 0x000000019bad4870
    sp: 0x000000016b2569d0   pc: 0x000000019bad487c cpsr: 0x60000000
```

Comment: It actually crashed in your app from the following line: MyApp                           0x0000000104babe54 0x104ba4000 + 32340. Try symbolicate this line and find where  it actually crashed. The documentation can be found in here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: @meim - Sorry, I should have posted the correct one

49 MyApp                    0x1009f3e54 main (AppDelegate.swift:20)

Comment: I think ARC is deallocating object and you are trying to access that object. please debug through code and see all variable values on debug area.

Comment: How do I debug through code if I can't reproduce

Comment: @JoshFeinberg hey I am seeing same kinda crash, do you know how to debug? I can't reproduce these kinda crash as well.

Comment: @va05 - ended up being something like I had deleted the view from my storyboard but not the outlet in my code. basically a null pointer reference

Comment: @JoshFeinberg - I had the exact same issue and in the end it turned out to be using Colors stored in the app's bundle. For some reason on iOS12, accessing these caused a near identical crash log to yours. All I did was remove this from a component and the crash was resolved.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue with one of my app with only 10% of my production user's experiencing a crash. Did you resolve this?